# Attaching GDB to a specific fork

Tags: linux, gdb, multi-process

I am trying to reverse engineer a Linux binary that makes several `fork()` calls. I am using GDB 7.5 on Ubuntu. What I am trying to do with GDB is attach to a certain `fork()` (say the second call). Is the only way to do this to set `follow-fork-mode` to `child` and catch all calls to `fork` and manually switch it each time?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `set detach-on-fork off`, as said in the documentation:

> `set detach-on-fork MODE`
>        Tells gdb whether to detach one of the processes after a fork, or
>        retain debugger control over them both.

The documentation says also this:

> If you choose to set `detach-on-fork` mode off, then GDB will retain
>   control of all forked processes (including nested forks).  You can list
>   the forked processes under the control of GDB by using the
>   `info inferiors` command, and switch from one fork to another by using
>   the `inferior` command
>
> To quit debugging one of the forked processes, you can either detach
>   from it by using the `detach inferiors` command (allowing it to run
>   independently), or kill it using the `kill inferiors` command.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is how I've typically approached this.  Setting a breakpoint on `fork` itself provides a nice spot to change this mode, if necessary.

Or, if the child threads / processes are "stable", you can switch to them after the fact with the [`inferior` command](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inferiors-and-Programs.html).

http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html